# Return more than one JSX element from a function React-Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to return more than one JSX Element from a function without wrapping it with something like `View`.

i found some solutions about React but not sure if they result the same in react native.

What i'm doing now:

```
renderElements() {
      return (
         <View>
           <Text>1st text</Text> 
           <Text>2nd text</Text>
           <Text>3rd text</Text> 
          </View>
      );
 }
```

What i want but doesn't work:

```
renderElements() {
          return (   
               <Text>1st text</Text> 
               <Text>2nd text</Text>
               <Text>3rd text</Text> 
          );
     }
```

i know its not possible to return multiple values from function but what i need is to not wrap them inside a `<View>`. i hope i could say what i mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

You can use `<></>` or `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>`

```
renderElements() {
      return (
          <>
              <Text>1st text</Text> 
              <Text>2nd text</Text>
              <Text>3rd text</Text> 
          </>
      );
}
```

Comment: is it equal to 3 divided elements (consider 3 thing returned by 3 functions)?

Comment: @Amas What do you mean by `3 divided elements` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should always have one parent wrapping all component inside render function. You cannot use 3 Views or other things as parent component. Although there is Fragment component you can wrap all of them with `<React.Fragment> </React.Fragment>`.